# Fatal error: Call to undefined function cmsms_theme_page_layout_scheme()

Tags: plugins, functions, themes, fatal-error

I am using a modified version of the Social Activity theme from CMS Masters, and was trying to change the hardcoded versioning of the stylesheet in the header in order to reflect CSS changes I made.

However, the site has suddenly stopped working. None of the page or post content after the header menu loads; instead, I get this fatal error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function cmsms_theme_page_layout_scheme() in /home4/f7d1q9f4/public_html/wp-content/themes/social-activity/header.php on line 293`

This is the line in `header.php` that it's referring to:

`list($cmsms_layout, $cmsms_page_scheme) = cmsms_theme_page_layout_scheme();`

I did not edit this line.

You can see the live site here: http://www.emergemiami.com/

According to my research, this often occurs when the theme requires certain plugins that aren't installed or activated. The issue is that all of the required plugins (CMSMasters Content Composer, CMSMasters Contact Form Builder, and CMSMasters Mega Menu) **are** activated.

I've already tried re-naming the plugins folder to deactivate all the plugins and re-activate them again, but with all of the non-required plugins off I still get the error message. Does anyone have suggestions on how I can fix this?

I am on a hostgator server and running WordPress 4.8.5 (I know we should upgrade, but I don't want anything to stop working and i'm not the only one working on this site).

Comment: You mention that you made some changes and things stopped working, can you outline the changes you made, perhaps with some actual code? Have you tried reverting the changes to be sure what you did is causing the problem?

Comment: @totels thank you. I don't remember exactly what I changed (potentially in theme-functions.php in the theme framework), but I found an old theme backup and that fixed the problem. There may be some minor theme updates that were made in the meantime, but i'll check with the other people who have also been working on this project because they weren't significant. Thanks!